# How to call an elisp command to edit the current buffer from within a custom command

Tags: emacs

I am trying to create a custom emacs command to remove blank lines from the region. I found an interactive way to do this at [masteremacs](https://www.masteringemacs.org/article/removing-blank-lines-buffer) using this command:

```
M-x flush-lines RET ^\s-*$ RET
```

Since I have to do this often, I'd like to create my own command for it, like so:

```
(defun flush-empty-lines (start end)                                                                                                
  (interactive "*r")                                                                                                                
  (flush-lines "^\s-*$" start end))
```

However, when I select a region and do `M-x flush-empty-lines RET`, nothing happens. I've tried tweaking the call to `flush-lines` in various ways, such as passing the region boundaries and setting `(INTERACTIVE t)`, but nothing has worked.

In general, is some kind of special syntax required to pass control from one interactive function to another?

**EDIT:** I revised my code per @Drew's comment (thanks), but it still isn't working.

Comment: My bad, that was a typo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gotta pay the backslash tax (this is a regexp syntax bug, not an interactivity bug):

```
(defun flush-empty-lines (start end)                                                                                                
  (interactive "*r")                                                                                                                
  (flush-lines "^\\s-*$" start end))
```

Answer (score 1):

@jpkotta's answer is correct of course, but it's worth pointing out `repeat-complex-command` which is a handy Emacs feature for repeating commands that read at least one of their arguments via the minibuffer, as it will show you *exactly* how those interactive arguments ended up being treated.

- <kbd>M-x</kbd> `flush-lines` <kbd>RET</kbd> `^\s-*$` <kbd>RET</kbd>
- <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>M-:</kbd> or <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>ESC</kbd><kbd>ESC</kbd>

Which then gives you a prompt with the elisp code:

```
Redo: (flush-lines "^\\s-*$" nil nil t)
```

Your issue was just one of syntax, but this feature gets even more useful when the interactive minibuffer input is *different* to the equivalent elisp argument.  E.g.:

<kbd>M-x</kbd> `align-regexp` <kbd>RET</kbd> `foo` <kbd>RET</kbd>

```
Redo: (align-regexp 655 848 "\\(\\s-*\\)foo" 1 1 nil)
```